# runtime sounds overlap with actionscript 3 on flash 9

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, swfloader, flashplayer-9

Having a problem with AS3, Flash player 9: When using the following code.

I cant stop the sounds on the unloaded swf from playing back after a new SWF is loaded??

I've tried putting a sound mixer stop all code on the actions panel of the opening frame for all my swf's. I have this code in my main swf, the sounds are in the loaded swf's.

I'm using Flash player 9, AS3, Flash CS5

```
var Xpos:Number = 53;
var Ypos:Number = 17;
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

var defaultSWF:URLRequest = new URLRequest("swfs/Animation1.swf");

loader.load(defaultSWF);
loader.x = Xpos;
loader.y = Ypos;
addChild(loader);


 Btns Universal function
 function btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

removeChild(loader);
    var newSWFRequest:URLRequest = 
 new URLRequest("swfs/" + event.target.name + ".swf");
loader.load(newSWFRequest);
loader.x = Xpos;
     loader.y = Ypos;
addChild(loader);

 }
 // Btn listeners
ActivatePart1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
ActivatePart2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
ActivatePart3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
Certificates.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
```

Comment: i'm curious why you are targeting FP9?

Comment: Flash 10 will not load swf's without exported text or embeded text... i did embed and it still wouldnt work. so i published at FP9 and that fixed the issue. thats the only reason i used the FP9 setting...

Comment: i don't understand that problem without further detail but it's a bad idea to target FP9 over FP10.2.  i would suggest posting a new question to solve that issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `Loader.unloadAndStop()` before loading a new swf in your `Loader`?

Comment: Looks like they're targeting Flash player 9 which doesn't support unloadAndStop

Comment: Im using        loader.load(newSWFRequest);                       should I change that?

Comment: jpea is right. @Ian, you should at least try unloading before reloading. Or you could compile for Flash 10 by selecting ActionScript Settings > Default Linkage > Merged into code.